# matplotlib is not showing a sharp image. the lines are in comic style. how can I make that to normal?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = "sans-serif"

plt.xkcd()

dev_x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

dev_y = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000] 

plt.plot(dev_x,dev_y)

plt.show()
```

the graph lines here are not sharp
[image]

also I get this after running the code
[image]

I want a straight lines instead of this comic style

Answer (score 1):

Remove or comment the line `plt.xkcd()`

- This mode is intended to create amusing charts that resemble hand-drawn charts.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you use `plt.xkcd` in the first place? Don't use this command if you don't want its effect.

[`plt.xkcd`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xkcd.html) is specifically made to plot wavy lines and funny fonts in the spirit of the [`xkcd`](https://xkcd.com/) webcomic:

[image]

To restore "normal" plotting remove the `plt.xkcd` and restart your interpreter or use:

```
plt.rcdefaults()
```